# Trimming String type properties within an object to remove spaces

Tags: java

I would like to ask, I have a complex Java object. Inside this object, it may contain String types, as well as other objects (which may also have String type properties), object collections (where the objects in the collection may also contain String type properties), and List. I need to trim all the String type properties within this complex object to remove leading and trailing spaces. Thank you all.

I tried using a convert JSON string and it obviously didn't work for me

Comment: Are you saying that you need to convert a JSON string to this complex Java object?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.